# White screen of death on php site for certain query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, error-log

Hi im experiencing white screen of death on my php site which only occurs given a certain query and i cant seem to find any errors . I tried looking at var/logs/apache2 and looked for php error log and there was none.

I am using yii. I have a page which list filtered contents. In my controller, i have like a query :

```
     $model= Person::model()->findbyPk('12345');
     $list = $model->contacts;
```

The 'contacts' is a relation of 'person' model, and the list is what i should display. If i query people with keys '12345', '14256,  and '23489', The page will show properly. But when I query a particular '10012', it will give me a white screen with no errors and no style format. Just a blank screen. And it also loads really load longer than other queries. I tried logging it and check in the shared-data/runtime but it wont even reach the controller. It just happens for this certain Person.

What seems to be the most likely cause of this?

Comment: Is there an entry in your database with a person id of 10012? What does your `findbyPk()` method return if there is no matching row in the database? Maybe you should check `$model` to see if it's an object before you dereference it.

Comment: Can you add some debug information? maybe as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177980/fatal-error-handling-in-yii). Try to setup some unit test using that particular id and see any errors reported there.

Comment: Run that query outside your php application and see what it returns.  White screens are often indicative of too much data.

Comment: save the returned value to a session variable, check post that with an id the process runs fine with and dump the session variable, tell us what that brings up.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, @DanBracuk was right. If your comment was only an answer id upvote it. I was experiencing too much data i think. Im sure i have model 12345 because i myself checked it on the database. There was just too many contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was there was too much data in `Person` model's relation `contacts`. The relation was one to many. Solution was getting contacts using another way/query.

What i am still not sure about is why when i log inside the controller where i run the query, it would not even reach the controller. Even though the log was was before the query was run, e.g.

```
   function actionListContacts() {
        Yii::log('Ireached this function');
        $request = Yii::app()->request;
        $personId = $request->get('personId');

        $model = Person::model()->findByPk($personId);
        // This is where the query for contacts should start..
        $contacts = $person->contacts;

        $this->render(['contacts' => $contacts]);
   }
```

If i use id '12345', render is successful and if i check the logs, i can see my log. But when i use 10012, which caused the white page and i checked the logs, it didnt even reach the controller. And by the way, id '10012' is existing checked the database myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you are getting result in your $model or not. Try this

```
$model= Person::model()->findbyPk('12345');
if($model=== NULL)
{
throw new CHttpException('I am empty. Please try another key');
}
else
{
// whatever you wanna do
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1) Enable Yii DEBUG mode. 2) Enable all error reporting on php.3) Enable Yii Profiling with help of [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#profiling-sql-executions). and do check Person model before using it like below .

```
$model= Person::model()->findbyPk('12345');
if($model === NULL)
{
throw new CHttpException('There is no record with this key.');
}
// Normal expected code .
```

Comment: Sorry but i was sure that the key isn't empty. Checked the database myself. If model was a null, im sure Yii would throw an error 'Trying to get the attribute of a non-object property', or something like that. HAve experienced it a lot of times before.