# Yii - errors not appearing just get a white screen

Tags: php, debugging, yii, fatal-error

For some reason I cannot see any PHP errors in the browser, I know there is an error but the screen is just white, I would be expecting the Yii themed error page with the stack trace (nothing in the logs either)

Any ideas? My config is below

I have in my config the following:

```
'yiiDebug' => true
'yiiTraceLevel => 6
```

And the following in my components array

```
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                'web'=>array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'trace, info, error, warning, application',
                    'categories'=>'system.db.*',
                    'showInFireBug'=>false
                ),
                'file'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, watch',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Did you look in Yii's error log or your PHP/webserver's error log? A white screen can indicate a fatal error that Yii cannot catch and display. (Your config snippet is missing a comma at the end of the first line, for starters.)

Comment: The weird thing is... the error happens but doesnt appear to show anything in the logs or on the screen however the Yii database debugging still shows on the page?? How odd?

Answer (score 0):

By default yii cant catch php fatal errors or server errors. There is some module which maybe help you with fatal errors : https://github.com/psrustik/yii-fatal-error-catch
or solutions how to catch it : [Fatal error handling in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177980/fatal-error-handling-in-yii)
If it is not a production site, turn on php errors display or check php and servers logs

Answer (score 0):

I would look in the server's error logs. If you are using apache you can find them in /var/log/apache2/. It should be an error.log or {domain}-error.log file.